# is this good design for CoreData application in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

this is my first app I am trying to do with CoreData. So far I am going with a lazy approach and I would like to ask whether what I am thinking makes sense.

So, here is what I have know :

For all tableviewDataSource delegate methods I have something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self numberOfActiveLeagues];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self fetchSectionTitleForId:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section+1]];
}
```

The same applies for

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So, each of the methods I am calling makes a NSFetchRequest and gets the data. For example, take a look at these two :

```
-(NSString*) fetchSectionTitleForId:(NSNumber*)leagueId
{
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entityGW = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"League" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"leagueId", leagueId];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityGW];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSError *fetchError = nil;
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];

    if (!fetchError) {
        for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in result) {

            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , GW : %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"leagueName"],[[managedObject valueForKey:@"gameweeks"] valueForKey:@"gwId"]];
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching data.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", fetchError, fetchError.localizedDescription);
        return @" ";
    }
    return @" ";
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfActiveLeagues
{
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entityLeague = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"League" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityLeague];


    NSError *fetchError = nil;
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];

    if (!fetchError) {
        return [result count];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching data.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", fetchError, fetchError.localizedDescription);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Right now, it seems to me that this is too much for doing that like this - the methods and the access to my data should perform a number of times.

So, 1st question is how bad design is this?

I have thought of doing something like this:

Have some variables, let's say :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sectionTitles;
```

and assign value to them during viewDidLoad. Similarly for the others as well. Also, I will make sure every time my CoreData need to be updated I update my local variables and I reload my table data.

is that better? Do I gain anything?

And if not, what's the best approach for fetching core data and presenting data to a tableview? I need to have more than one `NSFetchedControllers` and based on the timestamp I might need to fetch new data from the server, or delete some of my core data entries etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, 1st question is how bad design is this?

**Very**, but there's hope. With your current code you're doing 2*(number of sections) + 1 fetches to get data you could get in one fetch. Fetches are relatively expensive (slow) operations, so you should minimize the number of fetches. Performing a fetch in a callback from a table view is likely to cause poor UI performance.

Your idea of doing a single fetch into a `sectionTitles` array is much better. If you're already using `NSFetchedResultsController`, you might be able to improve things even more by using `sectionNameKeyPath:`. Then you can just get section info from the `NSFetchedResultsController` without doing a separate fetch.

Comment: So, if I have a NSFetchedResultsController which brings the results and then I just get the section Info, this should be better. I found an example from Apple, so I am going to try it. Thanks!